# PostgreSQL How to check range of integer in case statement

Tags: postgresql

I am having problem to fetch query in which i have a check user score in range to display the grade if user score between 75 and 100 then its A. If user score between 60- 75 then its B and .. so on .

I am getting this values

```
CASE users.points_earned
WHEN  75-100 THEN
    'A+'
WHEN  60-75 THEN
    'A'
WHEN  40-60 THEN
    'B+'
WHEN  1--40 THEN
    'B'
ELSE
    'Absent'
    end as rank
```

buts not working how to check range in case statement of postgresql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [BETWEEN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-comparison.html) for check ranges.

```
WITH users(points_earned) as(
    select 75
    union all
    select 90
    union all
    select 200
)

SELECT CASE 
WHEN users.points_earned BETWEEN 40 AND 75 THEN 'A+'
WHEN users.points_earned BETWEEN 76 AND 100 THEN 'A'
ELSE 'Absent'
END as rank 
FROM users
```

Comment: @FerozSiddiqui BTW because the `case` statement returns the first satisfied condition it could be simplified like `case when users.points_earned < 40 then 'B' when users.points_earned < 60 then 'B+' ... end`